# How to avoid :hidden: source file from getting added as bookmarks in Sphinx pdflatex generated pdf file

Tags: python-sphinx, pdflatex

Using Sphinx documentation generator (with pdflatex), I am creating **pdf files** and have added links to some of the internal files using `label` and `ref` markups like this:

**In the called file (xyz.rst)**

```
.. _called-file-label:
```

**In the calling file(abc.rst)** I am adding a reference to the `label` like this:

```
:ref:`Get Info <called-file-label>`
```

With the above arrangement, I am able to generate pdf file using **pdflatex**. However, I find that the called file is also added to the pdf file's bookmarks section which feels *somewhat clumsy*.

I understand I need to add both the source files in the `.. toctree::` section for the hyperlink to appear in the pdf file (I have added the **called file** using `:hidden:` directive to prevent the file from showing up in the html document's ToC tree).

**My question is:** What do I need to do in order that the called file (**xyz.rst**) does not figure in the **bookmarks section** of the **generated pdf file**?

Comment: I would not try to hide something in the PDF document. Use something like an addendum/appendix section instead of hiding elements from the bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

If after `.. _called-file-label:` label is section:

```
.. _called-file-label:

Foo Bar
======
```

Then, the section title "Foo Bar" will always become a bookmark in PDF.

The `:hidden:` option of `toctree` is not to hide documents, but to don't show ToC on the place with `toctree`. I.e. it is to hide toctree, not its documents. Documents in hidden toctree will still be visible in HTML sidebars, PDF bookmarks, etc.

It looks like you need [rubric directive](https://blog.documatt.com/restructuredtext-sphinx/sections.html#rubrics). Rubric is like a section, but doesn't make up the table of contents.